# While loop only runs once although it should run more than once

Tags: php, while-loop

I have a database table which stores which days (Monday to Sunday) are working days and which are not. The table includes 2 attributes, "day" (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 for Monday to Sunday) and "working". I use the numbers '0' and '1' to indicate if they are working days or not, '1' being non working day. I have set in the database for Friday, Saturday and Sunday to be nonworking (5, 6, 7).

```
$addrange = $annstart;
    $minusday = 0; //numbers of nonworking days

    $resultnonworking = mysql_query("SELECT dayid FROM workingdays WHERE working='1'");
    while ($nonworking = mysql_fetch_array($resultnonworking))
    {
        while ($datediffdays > 1)
            {
                $addrange = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($addrange . ' + 1 day'));
                $daycheck = date('N', strtotime($addrange));
                if ($daycheck == $nonworking['dayid'])
                    {
                        $minusday = ++$minusday;
                    }               
                $datediffdays = --$datediffdays;
            }
        $startdaycheck = date('N', strtotime($annstart));
        if ($nonworking['dayid'] == $startdaycheck)
        $minusday = ++$minusday;    
    }
```

However my while loop only runs once and checks which of the dates are Fridays, leaving out Saturday, and Sunday.

Can somebody spot what is wrong with my code?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is $datediffdays defined?

Comment: What is this code actually trying to achieve? Are you trying to count the amount of non-working days? You could just use `COUNT` in a MySQL query.

Comment: @cornelb It is defined in the top part of the code which I did not paste.

Comment: @SamV I have a range of dates, which I need to find how many of them are non-working days. The non-working days may not be weekends and are stored in a table.

Comment: please tell us how the range of date is stored (you seem to have a starting date that you add days to) - what is the end of the range? Also, how are you using $datediffdays? What is the initial value? If you just want too see how many days from a range are non-working, there should be an easier way

Comment: @cornelb The end of the range is the last day of a given date range. For example if I am given 2014-01-01 to 2014-01-04, the range would be  2014-01-02 2014-01-03 2014-01-04.The starting date would be 2014-01-01.

I am using $datediffdays to calculate how many days I must add to the starting date to get the range.

Yes, what I am trying to achieve is to find how many non-working days are there from the range. However, the data for which days are non-working are stored in a table. Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Explanation to what you asked, your loop is as below.

```
while ($nonworking = mysql_fetch_array($resultnonworking))
{
    while ($datediffdays > 1)
    {
```

see it first fetches one record and then until the `$datediffdays` goes less then 1 it runs the inner loop.
now when you come back to the first loop the value of `$datediffdays` is already less than 1 so it doesn't goes into the second loop.
to make this workig you have to initialize `$datediffdays` inside first loop like,

```
while ($nonworking = mysql_fetch_array($resultnonworking))
{
    $datediffdays = 5;
    while ($datediffdays > 1)
    {
```

where as the changes that you made now, fetces the record inside the while loop and then it reduces the value of `$datediffdays` variable only once a loop
and therefore it is working, because value of `$datediffdays` is not set to less than 1 the first time it comes inside the loop.

I can't suggest which will be the best approach as all of your code is not here

Answer (score 0):

I've switched the inner while loop with the outer one, and with a little bit of changes, its working now. But I have no idea why it is working this way but not the other.

```
$addrange = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($annstart . ' - 1 day'));
    $minusday = 0; //numbers of nonworking days

    while ($datediffdays > 0)
        {
            $addrange = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($addrange . ' + 1 day'));
            $checkrange = date('N', strtotime($addrange));
            $resultnonworking = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM workingdays WHERE working='1'");
            while ($nonworkingcheck = mysql_fetch_array($resultnonworking))
                {
                    if($nonworkingcheck['dayid'] == $checkrange)
                        {

                            $minusday = $minusday + 1;

                        }
                }
            $range = $range." ".$addrange;
            $datediffdays = $datediffdays-1;
        }

    $range = substr($range,11);
```